# CardLayout method show() not working in awt

Tags: java, layout, awt

I am trying to run `CardLayout` but don't know why `show()` of `CardLayout` is not working. I am getting error.

```
package java_files;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

//import javax.swing.JButton;

public class AwtLayoutExample  {
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      Frame f=new Frame("Card Layout");
      f.setSize(400,400);
      f.setVisible(true);
      f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
              System.exit(0);
          }
      });
      CardLayout card=new CardLayout();
      f.setLayout(card);
      Panel panelCont=new Panel();
      Panel panelFirst=new Panel();
      Panel panelSecond=new Panel();
      Button b1=new Button("Switch to 2nd Panel");
      Button b2=new Button("Switch to 1st Panel");
      panelFirst.add(b1);

      panelSecond.add(b2);
      panelFirst.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
      panelSecond.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
      panelCont.add(panelFirst,"1");
      panelCont.add(panelSecond, "2");
      card.show(panelCont, "1");      
      b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      card.show(panelCont, "2");
      }
      });
      b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
              card.show(panelCont, "2");
          }
      });
      f.add(panelCont);
      f.pack();
      f.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

I just get a blank frame when I run it along with this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong parent for CardLayout
    at java.awt.CardLayout.checkLayout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.CardLayout.show(Unknown Source)
    at java_files.AwtLayoutExample.main(AwtLayoutExample.java:33)
```

Comment: You apply `CardLayout` to the `Frame`, but use `panelCont` as the container you are trying to switch. Have a look at [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).  Also, the AWT API was superseded by Swing some 16+ years ago, you'd get better support for Swing and JavaFX then you will for AWT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply CardLayout to Panel and then add other Panels to this Panel

```
Panel panelCont=new Panel(new CardLayout());
panelCont.add("one", panelOne);
panelCont.add("two", panelTwo);
panelCont.add("three", panelThree);
```

When show you can do like this:

```
((CardLayout) panelCont.getLayout()).show(panelCont, "two");
```

Comment: Thanks its working. But I think its because of awt its little complex. Using swings its simpler.

Comment: CardLayout is the same in both of them, but I suggest you use Swing, it is more better